# how to move multiple folders into 1 folder

Tags: java, file

I have a directory `C:\Test\` that have several files and folder

```
 example :
 C:\Test\new1.txt
 C:\Test\document.xls
 C:\Test\presentation.pdf
 C:\Test\pro_country
 C:\Test\pro_libs
 C:\Test\misc
 C:\Test\pro_bin
 C:\Test\mug
```

I want to MOVE (not copy ) all the folders that starts with `pro` into one folder

so ill have such direcotry

```
 example :
 C:\Test\new1.txt
 C:\Test\document.xls
 C:\Test\presentation.pdf
 C:\Test\misc
 C:\Test\mug
 C:\Test\Newprofolder
```

I tried this code but I didn't know how to return the result from list files to copy them to the directory

```
File[] proList = direct.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {

        return name.startsWith("Pro");
    }
});

String pFileDest = directory + "//" + "pcore.war";
File filepldst = new File(pFileDest);
File filePortalSrc = new File(pLocation);

try {
    FileUtils.copyFile(filePortalSrc, filepldst);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Java nio has `Files#move` (which I recommend as it does not copy for moves on the same filesystem).

Comment: What you ask is unclear, are you asking how to move a file or how to use `proList` content?

Comment: how to move the pro list contents

Answer (score 0):

```
Files.move(new File("C:\\projects\\test").toPath(), new File("C:\\projects\\dirTest").toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Change source and destination path